# How do I use rsync shared folders in Vagrant on Windows?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, rsync, shared-directory

I’m using Laravel Homestead to develop projects locally. Requesting a single view takes up to 6 seconds, so I wanted to increase the performance with rsync.

I installed cwRsync into a “C:\rsync” folder and added “C:\rsync\bin” to my PATH variable.

In the cmd the “rsync” command works fine globally but after I triggered “vagrant up” I get this error:

```
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...

==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...

"rsync" could not be found on your PATH. Make sure that rsync
is properly installed on your system and available on the PATH.
```

What can I do so vagrant recognizes rsync? Like I said, it works fine in the windows commandline.
Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176041/vagrant-with-virtualbox-on-windows10-rsync-could-not-be-found-on-your-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the directory/folder to the USER PATH instead of SYSTEM PATH.

Try that and it will work.

If you have further problems just install cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by installing `Cygwin` and modified the PATH variable to have the `rsync` path. Here are the steps I followed - on a Windows 7 laptop. It's too late but writing this for some new people who are starting to play around `vagrant`.

1. Install `cygwin` 64bit
2. While installing it will ask for selecting the components
3. In the search box, search for `rsync`
4. Navigate to Net and click until you see Install. If you click on the version, you can change the version too. I have installed 3.1.1 but there is 3.2 as well.
5. Once the installation is done, navigate to `c:\cygwin64\bin` and verify if rsync file exists. This is the default install path. In case if you have changed the path while installing, you can scroll to the respective path.
6. Right Click My Computer --> Properties --> Advanced System Settings --> Advanced(tab) --> Click the *Environment Variables* button in the bottom right
7. There are 2 sections in this tiny window. Go to the bottom section, "System Variables" --> Select Path --> Click Edit. Take at most care while editing this.
8. Append the path in the end but prefixing ";".

   Example: 
   C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\CCM;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\cygwin64\bin
9. Save it and close all the windows.
10. Now if you run the PATH command in the existing window where "vagrant up" was ran it wont show the updated path. (I am trying to figure out how to make the current window itself to recognize that updated PATH like we do in Linux. Not good on Windows) .
11. Open a new Command window (CMD.EXE), run PATH command and there it will display the `Cygwin` appended path in the end.
12. Now run vagrant up and that should bring up the VM.